# Cumulative sum over days

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL table like the following:

```
date         count
2010-01-01   5
2010-01-02   6
2010-01-03   7
```

How can I accumulate the sum of each day to the next one? So the result is like:

```
date         acum per day
2010-01-01   5
2010-01-02   11
2010-01-03   18
```

I think i need some kind of for(each date)... but no clue.

---

Just the final query i used following answer from Eric. (thanks).

SELECT t1.dia, sum(t2.operacions), sum(t2.amount) FROM

```
(SELECT count(*) operations, sum(amount), date(b.timestamp) dia
    FROM transactions b group by date(b.timestamp)) t1 

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT count(*) operations, sum(amount), date(b.timestamp) dia
    FROM transactions b group by date(b.timestamp)) t2 

ON t2.dia <= t1.dia GROUP BY t1.dia
```

Comment: What is the `date` data type?

Comment: Is a timestamp i'm converting with date() function.

Basically is a list of transactions and i need to find acumulated after each day.

Trying the solution now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think this would work, not sure how the performance would be though:

```
SELECT t1.date, sum(t2.count)
FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.date <= t1.date
GROUP BY t1.date
```

Comment: That assumes that all the `date` data is either a DATETIME data type, for the exact same time, or the column is [var]char which risks not evaluating correctly on the join.

Comment: @Ponies - That's right, if there was a time component to the date he would need to do some conversions to get just the date part.  Since he showed only dates in his question, I assumed that was all he was storing.

Comment: @Ponies - Also, Even if it's VARCHAR, looks like he's using YYYY-MM-DD format, so they should compare correctly even as strings.

Comment: This worked for me. Not aware it was possible to do this kind of conditional join! 

Very useful. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder what version of MySQL this worked on. Fails for me on 5.6 with 'Unknown Column t2.count in field list'.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to solve this problem without join.

```
SET @cumulative_sum := 0;
SELECT date, @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + count AS cumulative_sum
FROM table
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Self join with a <= and sum the row would accomplish this.